# Is this ER diagram correct?

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I am working on my first ER diagram, for a clothing brand case study. I was wondering if my work is correct. Any feedback is more than welcome. My most important concern is the key relationships between order, order item and product, which throw me off despite any changes I make.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: No,. it looks like incorrect (potentially contradictory).

Comment: I'm confused; "Shopping Cart" is drawn in as if it were a table, yet it seems to be just functions.